# How can I understand "from where" i came to onResume method?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity which is working in a tab. And sometimes, I'm setting this tab as a current tab.

What I want is to understand how `onResume()` function of this activity is called. After the creation of activity or because of setting the tab as a current tab? I tried setting a static variable of activity before setting the tab as a current tab, and check it in `onResume()` function.

I wonder if there is a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Activity lifecycle

[image: http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png]

[from the android activity documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to put timestamp before leaving onPause() and onStart() to detect which callback method was called earlier or a more brute force way is to throw and catch an exception and inspect the stack trace -- but this will slow down your app..